# Core Data Predicate Using KeyPath on a Collection

Tags: swift, core-data

I have the following code which returns all movies matching the actor name.

```
static func byActorName(name: String) -> [Movie] {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Movie> = Movie.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "actors.name CONTAINS %@", name)
    
    do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

The code above works, but how can I convert it to a modern Swift KeyPath approach?

I implemented the following code which works but I don't like the idea of writing `%K.name` syntax.

```
static func byActorName(name: String) -> [Movie] {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Movie> = Movie.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.name CONTAINS %@", #keyPath(Movie.actors), name)
    
    do {
        return try viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return []
    }
}
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Are you trying to turn the `name` part into a keypath expression too?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K CONTAINS %@", #keyPath(Movie.actors), #keyPath(Actor.name), name)
```

Comment: Actually once `%K` and `#keyPath(Movie.actors.name)` should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately Movie.actors.name did not work out.

Comment: and `#keyPath(actors.name)`?

Comment: Nope. actors is a set so that does not work. Error is: Ambiguous reference to member 'name'